# recommend a shape recognition library for the example image

Tags: image-processing

I need to find some library(can be commercial) to detect the rectangle shapes from pictures like this one:

[image]

What libraries do you think they can do the job?

Also, I know there are many algorithms in image processing, which one you think can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you need to detect? Text in rectagles? Number of shapes?

Comment: I need to create shapes based on the rectangles. The output needs to be the coordinates of these rectangles

Answer (score 3):

A quick attempt with Mathematica 8 produced this solution. It would be easy to play around some details.

Create a binary mask of the black ink, and then remove the small components (the digits):

```
binary = Binarize[img, .5];
bclean = ColorNegate[DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate[binary]]];
```

[image]
[image]

Now compute the connected components and remove the background component:

```
comp = DeleteBorderComponents[MorphologicalComponents[bclean]];
```

I assessed the result visually, using the command `Colorize[comp]`.

[image]

From there on, the command `ComponentMeasurements` would get you to further analysis of the blobs you are interested in (cf. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html).

Comment: Hello Matthias,  thank you for your comment! While what you showed is great, I need a library which I can code with in C++ or C#. Thanks!

Comment: I see that Mathematica does have a .NET library caled .NET/Link. What's not clear to me is if I need Mathematica installed too to run my application which uses the .NET/Link. Any ideas?

Comment: .NET/Link lets you call .NET from Mathematica and it lets .NET programs call Mathematica. You can see the docs at
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/tutorial/Overview.html

You could call to Mathematica from a C# program using .NET/Link,  so that you could use the image processing functions you are interested in.
You could also use a different linking technology,  MathLink, which
would let you call to Mathematica from C++.

Comment: Do I need Mathematica installed? If yes, it's not an option for me.

Comment: Do you mean locally? What deployment scenario do you have in mind? Sorry I need more input to understand your question.

Comment: I need a library which can be accessed in C#. The deployment should not be something like installing a full blown app like Mathematica.

Comment: it doesn't answer my question. Mathematica is not an answer.

Comment: I understand now that you have constraints when deploying your application. But these constraints were not stated in the original question. If you can not deploy using Mathematica, you can still use Mathematica for the prototyping.